# .net core launch with production profile after publishing

Tags: .net-core

I have a self hosted Web API with **Development** and **Production** profiles with corresponding listeners.
In **Development** the service is listening to local host.
In **Production** there should be another listener URL defined in **Production** profile.

How to start an .net Core application with a specific profile defined *launchSettings.json* after publishing it?

**Not** with *dotnet run --launch-profile "Production"* command, but simply by starting the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**launchSettings.json** only affects local development. The **launchSettings.json** file controls what environments you can run your app in using Visual Studio.Environment values set in **launchSettings.json** override values set in the system environment.
In order to setting the hosting environment for a .NET Core app you need to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. 
More Infos [here](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/) and [here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/working-with-environments-and-launch-settings-in-asp-net-core/)